# Retrieve only a particular number of child records

Tags: c#, entity-framework

If I write

```
db.Topics.Include("ChildTopics")
```

then it gives all the child comments for that. But what I want is only the top two child topics ordered by "childtopic created date".

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible to include only the first two via Include method. 
In your case, you can do this :

```
var firstTwo = from topic in datacontext.Topics
    select new { Topic= topic, ChildTopic= topic.ChildTopics.OrderBy(c => c.childtopic_created_date).Take(2) };
```

Comment: I will use this way to get the data, but i am getting type conversion error

my code is
IQueryable<Topic> latestTopics = (IQueryable<Topic>) db.Topic.Select(_x =>
                    new
                    {
                        Topic = _x,
                        A = _x.A, // some object
                        B = _x.B, // some object
                        ChildTopics = _x.ChildTopics.OrderBy(e => e.createddate).Take(2)
                    });

Comment: I am getting this error

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType0`4[Topic,A,B,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Topic]]]' to type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Topic]'.

Comment: with the select(new ..) you will get a IEnumerable<YourNewCustomObject> so it's normal to have a cast error. Avoid casting, let it be a "var latestTopics = db.Topic..." then use the properties created (Topic, A, B, ChildTopics)

Comment: Thanks Tahir, actually i need to serialize this data and send that data back to client. so i need that to be typecasted.

I will use some DTO method as mentioned in below post
http://forums.silverlight.net/p/196847/458163.aspx#458163

Answer (score 0):

Include does an early load of all dependencies, but I am not aware of a way to apply restrictions on this implementation.

An alternate way would be to shape the results like:

```
var comments = db.Topics.Select(_x=> 
                    new{
                        Topic = _x, 
                        TopTwoChildTopics = _x.ChildTopics.Top(2)
                       });
```

Comment: Thanks KRam, is there a way I can use It with IQueryable<Topic> 
since when i try to type cast it throws following error

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType0`4[Topic,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Topic]]]' to type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Topic]'.

Comment: It would give this error if you try to cast as the result of the above is an anonymous type, try performing a further select to get the Topic.